# How can I reuse a library in multiple WAR/EAR files deployed on an application server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, shared-libraries

I'm currently working on an ebanking platform, so out customers are banks. To extend this platform, we develop our own 'xDK' (development kit) for 3rd party developers (usually the banks themselves).

When xDK is used as a dependency (via maven or gradle), it brings along a lot of transitive dependencies in order to work (~25MB). I was trying to think of solutions to make the dependency a bit lighter to use (given that it needs all of its dependencies) which in turn will promote having smaller, more focused services (not exactly micro-services but at least a step closer).

The current situation's benefit is that every service/project can use its own version of xDK and it doesn't have to update until it needs to. The problem is that it doesn't scale. If we assume 100 WAR files having xDK as a dependency, we create a 2.5GB overhead on the application server (even if they all use the same version).

I'll list two options I was thinking of, but I'd like to know if there are better solutions for this problem. Feel free to ask for more info. Thanks in advance.

---

Similar to JavaEE components (JPA, JAX-RS, ...), we'll have an 'api' dependency and the implementation. The projects will only declare the 'api' as a provided dependency while the implementation will be provided like so:

## JBoss module

I haven't worked with other application servers. We (and our customers) only use JBoss EAP, so this might be a JBoss specific solution. We can create a JBoss module for xDK and then make every deployment depend on it via the JBoss deployment descriptor. The benefit is that we get rid of the multiple copies of the library, but we lose on version flexibility. This would mean that there needs to be some kind of governance on which version of xDK you code against in your service. Also, every time there is a breaking change, we'd need to update all services if we want to update the JBoss module to the latest version.

## Bundle in an EAR

EARs allow multiple WAR files in them and also jars as libs. xDK will be an EAR dependency. Again, we have the same pros and cons as the previous solution. This solution is JBoss independent. However, it needs an extra build step to collect all the projects and bundle them, which might be annoying for out customers if they need to bundle their own services.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the maven dependency `scope` of `provided` to declare that for the individual war files the jar file is provided outside of the war file, and then have another mechanism to inject the shared jar file into the application server?

c.f. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: The provided dependency scope was already mentioned in my question. The problem is how to provide the jar :P
The WAR files are 'sandboxed' so I don't think you can inject jars.

Comment: @Dimitrios -- Okay I guess I missed that.  Our environment is different that yours.  We don't have that many war files, and they are all from the same team.  So we can coordinate the injection of shared libraries in the app server.

Comment: How do you achieve the injection of the shared libraries?

Comment: @Dimitrios -- We have about 10 war files, but they are all maintained by the same team.  Our production environment has to be duplicated to multiple deployment sites, and we use RPM to do that (our servers Linux servers).  Each war file is installed with its own RPM file.  We coordinate our RPM files so that one of them copies the needed shared libraries, as part of the RPM install/upgrade steps, to the app web's shared lib folder.

Comment: Yeah your setup is quite different. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Dimitrios -- No problem.  Good luck!